# How to offset a single datetime value by a quarter, not a series?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a datetime column in a dataframe. I want to subtract 2 quarters from one such value to get the last date of the resulting quarter. I can do it for a series using

`inp_data['Year_month'] - inp_data['Year_month'].dt.quarter.map(pd.offsets.QuarterEnd)`

This does not work for a value by indexing using "loc", which I understand is not doable. I am stumbling to find the answer.

Reference datetime column:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
table= [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17)],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31)]]

inp_data= pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Year_month'])
inp_data['Quarter'] = inp_data['Year_month'].dt.quarter
inp_data['Offset'] = inp_data['Year_month'] - inp_data['Year_month'].dt.quarter.map(pd.offsets.QuarterEnd)
inp_data
```

[Dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jM37.png)

**EDIT:**

```
inp_data.loc[0, 'Year_month'] - inp_data.loc[0, Year_month'].quarter.map(pd.offsets.QuarterEnd)
```

This gives following error:
**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'map'**

I want to offset just one date by 2 quarters prior and get the quarter end date.

*Please tell me if I am missing something. This is my first proper question here.*

Comment: Could you make a series containing just the value you are interested in & use that to compute the value you want?

Comment: you can use `.loc` to assign values. i recommend showing us what you've tried and exactly what your output *should* be

Comment: @ScottHunter, I know that is possible. Keeping it as last resort just to not make things tedious.
I have edited the question.